# Electrum: seed is 0 length / empty

Tags: electrum, seed

I installed electrum a while back and noted down the 12 word seed. Haven't used it for a few months, but now when I go to view my seed (clicking on the seed icon on the bottom right of the GUI), it asks for my password, and then the dialogue says:

"Your wallet generation seed is:"

And the text box below is completely empty, underneath which it says:

"Please write down or memorize these 0 words (order is important)..."

A bit concerned my seed seems to have vanished. Any suggestions?

Comment: Odd. Can you still use your wallet?

Comment: @Nick See my answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question: appears I have uncovered a bug in electrum. The password I was entering was incorrect: the last 2 characters were wrong. However if I entered a completely wrong password I did get an "incorrect password" error, and the seed dialogue did not open.

Discovered by virtue of the command line console which did report incorrect password error when I entered the first wrong-by-two characters password.

Answer (score 2):

it is most likely this bug, fixed now: 
https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/commit/059d381ba8cfed0b4c00cb9b4ec1ff13293de74c

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how that commit is related to the asker's problem. Could you elaborate?

Comment: The asker was entering a wrong password, but instead of raising an exception the AES module was returning an empty string and that empty string was displayed as the seed. That commit replaces the faulty strip_PKCS7_padding function in the AES module, by a custom one that raises an exception.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense!